# What happened to post "Learning Python 3 from a Python 2 book?"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-questions

I noticed today that I had lost some points, because a post title *Learning Python 3 from a Python 2 book* had been removed. I have no way of finding out why it was removed.

Comment: Sounds like a not-constructive question, from that title alone, which would get it closed and deleted.

Comment: Here's the link for anyone who's interested: (10K only) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124383/learning-python-3-from-a-python-2-book

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124383/learning-python-3-from-a-python-2-book) was closed as `Not Constructive` by the community and then deleted by the community and a diamond moderator.

The question is a poor fit for Stack Overflow. I'm surprised it hadn't been deleted before now.

The text of the question:

> I bought a python 2 book a little while ago, planning to read it in a month. When I bought the book, I didn't know about Python 2.7 vs Python 3. The book is written in python 2.
>
> My question is, can I learn python 3 from this book?
>
> I've looked up the differences between the versions of the language but, since I haven't started learning it, I don't understand what most of them mean. Should I just pay for another book?

Normally I'd comment on the question and tell you why I feel like it's not constructive, but in this case I'll present the actual question asked, without comment:

**Should I pay for another book?**

Comment: Your explanation helps. Thanks.